# Springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor does not have createConnection(userid,pwd) method

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am writing sample Apache Camel (2.16.2) application that connects to IBM MQ queue manager in clients mode. Apache Camel uses Spring JMS underneath to connect to JMS providers. I see that  Spring `JmsAccessor` does not have a `createConnection`() method that takes UserId and Password. It only has `createConnection`() method that does not take any parameters. Because of this create connection to queue manager fails with 2035 - Not authorized.

I can connect to queue manager in server bindings mode but I need to connect in client mode as queue manager runs in a different machine. Is there a way I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `ConnectionFactory` in a [UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jms/connection/UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.html).