# JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq

I am using Websphere mq v 7.5. When I try to send message to Queue, I get following error :

> JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')
>   Provided Username and password are wrong.

I don't have any credentials to provide as it doesn't ask at time of installation. My camel-context configuration is given below:

```
 <bean id="webspheremq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="myConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="mqhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="1417"/>
    <property name="queueManager" value="QM1"/>
    <property name="channel" value="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"/>
    <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: This link may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103679/springframework-jms-support-jmsaccessor-does-not-have-createconnectionuserid-pw/35104433. I used code, not XML config file as you but I guess you can do the same in config file also.

Comment: @Shashi The OP said he doesn't have any credentials to provide.. The link you mentioned will ask to pass for credentials. I think you din't read his question properly. I am also facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 2):

The 2035 error you received will have more information to explain it in the queue manager error log. The fact that the JMS error message mentions a user ID and password is misleading, it could be one of a number of security failures, not necessarily that one, I suspect you are being caught by a default security rule (CHLAUTH rule) that bans the use of SYSTEM channels.

Look in your queue manager `AMQERR01.LOG` and then read the following post for more help on how to deal with a failure caused by a CHLAUTH rule.

[I'm being blocked by CHLAUTH - how can I work out why?](https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/blocked_by_chlauth_why/)